# Unable to fetch @CustomRequestParam values from swagger

Tags: java, rest, annotations, swagger

I am getting below error while running API from swagger:

```
2023-09-14 14:38:07.208  WARN 45800 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.w.r.a.GlobalControllerExceptionHandler : Error = [Missing Required Field(s).  Please refer to the API documentation] Exception = [Required request parameter 'documentIds' for method parameter type List is not present]
2023-09-14 14:38:07.217  WARN 45800 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.w.r.a.GlobalControllerExceptionHandler : Exception

org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'documentIds' for method parameter type List is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179) ~[spring-web-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-web-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
```

Below is my controller code and request data that I am passing from swagger

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST}, value = "/updateDocumentIds", headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ActionResult updateDocumentIds(@CustomRequestParam(value = "documentIds",required = true) List<String> documentIds, @RequestParam(value = "route") Boolean route) throws Exception {
        ActionResult actionResult = new ActionResult();
        //runs service method
        return actionResult;
    }
```

swagger request

[image]

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `@CustomRequestParam` we can use `@Requestbody` annotation, this will copy the data into list.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering

```
Required request parameter 'documentIds' for method parameter type List is not present
```

means that the Swagger request you are sending is not including the required `documentIds` parameter.

You need to fix your Swagger request like that

```
{
  "documentIds": [
    "Doc2133",
    "Doc2143",
    "Doc2153"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am getting same error. `{
  "actionStatus": 400,
  "message": "Missing Required Field(s)."
}`